# Share MS Project 2016 Calendar with Colleagues

Tags: calendar, share, ms-project

I created a new base calendar for use with projects I have created in work. As I had to create an extensive list of holidays in the 'Change Working Time' function, I need to share this with colleagues to prevent a lot of unnecessary manual work and to ensure everyone has the same list.

Is this possible? I cant find an export option anywhere for the calendars.

I have searched various links on Google and they just tell me how to create tasks or export to Excel, how to add new dates or calendars but nothing about sharing.

Is there a file pathway that i can find the file it's saved in and copy it to send to colleagues if I am not able to export it from Project itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Project has a tool called the [Organizer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-reports-calendars-and-views-in-project-78d9c687-b70f-4a20-86c5-e1c65c124261) which allows for copying objects such as views and calendars between projects. The Organizer is found on the File tab and looks like this:

[image]

In the lower left corner, select the file that contains the new custom calendar and in the lower right corner select the file that you want to copy it to. Then click the Calendar tab at the top of the window, select the name of the calendar on the left and click the Copy button to copy to the new file.

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for your reply. I had found the Organiser to copy the calendar from the project to the global template. However I'm assuming that will only apply to projects created using MS Project on my pc. What I need is to send the global template/base calendar to colleagues to use on MS Project on their pc so that they can use it when creating projects, and so that we all have the same list of excluded dates. Does that make sense? Is it possible? Thanks, Liam.

Comment: Copy the calendar to a new blank file (see screen shot, lower right corner) and send that file to the other users. They would then use the organizer to copy it into their project.

Comment: Thanks Rachel - the simplest solution ever, never even thought of that :-)

Comment: This is the purpose of the organizer ;)  Consider marking the answer as accepted so that the question no longer shows as waiting for an answer.